# mocha - chai : how to list all errors during a test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a unit test to contol a list of elements.

ex :

```
arr = [
{ element : "aaa",
  validation : false
},
{ element: "bbbb",
  validation: true
},
{ element: "ccc",
  validation: false
}
```

During my unit test , i want to list all invalid elements but with mocha and chai, he stop on the first invalid element.
How to force mocha to make a test with error ?

My code "it"  :

```
it('Read element', () => {
    let length = arr.length - 1;
      for (let i =0; i<= length; i++ ) {
    assert.equal(arr[i].validation, true, 'route ' + arr[i].element+ ' should be valid);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a separate test per array item:

```
describe('Read element', () => {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    it('route ' + item.element + ' should be valid', () => {
      assert.equal(item.validation, true);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [deepEqual](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepequal) matcher instead of looping over your array and construct an array to match against.

```
let validationArray = arr = [
{ element : "aaa",
  validation : true
},
{ element: "bbbb",
  validation: true
},
{ element: "ccc",
  validation: true
}];

assert.deepEqual(arr, validationArray);
```